# Connect to Redshift from Rackspace

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift, rackspace

I need some help in trying to connect to my redshift cluster from a rackspace box.

I can connect just fine from  my ec2 instances and also from my local machines. I have checked (and double checked) and verified all connection parameters and they turn out fine in my code, the only difference is of the environment, i.e when I try to connect from my ec2 instances, it works fine, but when trying to connect from my rackspace boxes, I get the following error

```
Connection to DB failed
could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "my_redshift_cluster_host_name" (cluster_ip) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port <cluster_port>?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In amazon console, For your redshift cluster , under security, in your security group could you check if you have added public IP under ( CIDR/IP)  for backspace box ?.

You need to authorise public IP for rackspace box.

Comment: I have a security group that is of `CIDR/IP` connection type with details `CIDR/IP:0.0.0.0/0`. Is this for a public setting?

Comment: You need put public ip 123.123.123.123/32 in CIDR/IP in redshift security group. Put public IP of your Rackspace box here.

Comment: Turns out it was just the iptables restricting the port on my rackspace box. Resolved it by adding an excrption for the particular port.